Calculate the buffer capacity of a mixture/solution?
I am planning an experiment where I am measuring the buffer capacity of a mixture. However the mixture has two weak acids in it. Will having multiple weak acids in the mixture cause any changes in the procedure? I

Calculate or measure? Measuring is the same, calculation is more complicated.

Yes it will make the system more complex to solve but not impossible, what is your acid?

@Poutnik I think its measuring? My aim is to titrate against a base to see how much is needed to change the pH of the mixture/solution though

@jlandercy it is an exfoliating serum so it has equal concentrations of glycolic acid and lactic acid in the serum

Measuring of pH buffer capacity does not care about the particular buffer composition. It just registers pH changes after addition of a strong base or acid.
The capacity can be expressed

absolutely ( in amount of acid/base )
relatively (in formally provided concentration of the strong
acid/base before it neutralizes the buffer counterpart.

Note also there is

the differential buffer capacity

absolute $\dfrac{\text{d}n}{\text{d(pH)}}$
relative $\dfrac{\text{d}c}{\text{d(pH)}}$


the integral buffer capacity

absolute $\Delta n$ for $\Delta \text{pH}=1$
relative $\Delta c$ for $\Delta \text{pH}=1$



For more, you may want to review search results for
site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org  "pH buffer" capacity

Thank you so much for clearing it up for me!
